# Two-level type hierarchy with Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I want to model 4 kinds of directions in my application: right, left, up and down. However, I want to be able to have a function that takes only the horizontal ones for a variable and the vertical ones for other variable.

To solve this, I can have two types: HorizontalDirection and VerticalDirection:

```
data HorizontalDirection = RightDir | LeftDir
data VerticalDirection = UpDir | DownDir

foo :: HorizontalDirection -> VerticalDirection -> String
foo hDir vDir = "This works"
```

However, I also would like to be able to have a function that can take one type as well as the other, something like this:

```
bar :: Direction -> String
bar (HorizontalDirection _) = "Horizontal!"
bar (VerticalDirection _)   = "Vertical!"
```

but this wouldn't work since HorizontalDirection and VerticalDirection aren't data constructors.

I know I can use Either and make it work, like this:

```
bar :: (Either HorizontalDirection VerticalDirection) -> String
bar (Left _) = "Horizontal!"
bar (Right _) = "Vertical!"
```

however, I wonder if I can do this without the Either type.

I also tried using typeclasses:

```
data HorizontalDirection = RightDir | LeftDir
data VerticalDirection = UpDir | DownDir

class Direction a

instance Direction HorizontalDirection
instance Direction VerticalDirection

baz :: Direction d => d -> String
baz RightDir = "Horizontal"
```

but that gives me the following compiler error:

```
Direction.hs:21:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘d’
                  with actual type ‘HorizontalDirection’
      ‘d’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          baz :: forall d. Direction d => d -> String
        at Direction.hs:20:1-33
    • In the pattern: RightDir
      In an equation for ‘baz’: baz RightDir = "Horizontal"
    • Relevant bindings include
        baz :: d -> String (bound at Direction.hs:21:1)
```

Is my way of thinking totally wrong here? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what your objection is to using `Either` here. If it's just the names of the constructors, you can always make your own sum type, like `data Direction = Horizontal HorizontalDirection | Vertical VerticalDirection`

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous, you might look at [union types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/union-0.1.2/docs/Data-Union.html).

Comment: @RobinZigmond, it's not a problem. I just felt that it was wrong because I always see Either as a means of error handling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `Either` you can declare a new data type with more meaningful names.

```hs
data Direction
  = Horizontal HorizontalDirection
  | Vertical   VerticalDirection

bar :: Direction -> String
bar (Horizontal _) = "Horizontal!"
bar (Vertical _) = "Vertical!"
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You are quite close, but you need to define the function *in* the class:

```
class Direction a where
    baz :: a -> String

instance Direction HorizontalDirection where
    baz _ = "Horizontal"

instance Direction VerticalDirection where
    baz _ = "Vertical"
```

Note however that Haskell is statically typed, and the types are known at compile time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, I think that @Li-yao Xia's answer is the one because it does not require typeclasses.